# Linq statement looking in a row and check if the value in column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq statement which looks in a datatable and looks at specific row and checks if the column in that row equals the value, this is working I was just wondering if there is a better way to write this

```
bool isExisting = DataTable.AsEnumerable()
                           .Where(x => x.Field<int>("Column5") == 2)
                           .Any(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnName") == specificNAme);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `Where` and `Any`:

```
bool isExisting = DataTable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Any(x => x.Field<int>("Column5") == 2 && 
                      x.Field<string>("ColumnName") == specificNAme);
```